# Database Server froze - High IO - how do I find out whats the reason? (Pics)

Tags: database, mariadb

got a db server(KVM) running mariadb 10.1, runs fine since months, only servers 2 databases (drupal). Last night it went tits up. Here 2 screenshots from zabbix

[image: cpu]

[image: io]

I checked the logs, they show nothing. All I got is system message: TASK mysqld (& other running tasks) blocked for more than 120 seconds.

Any idea how to investigate further?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Forgot to add: The VM was unresponsive for ACPI reboot, had to force reset.

Comment: Your server had a problem with its storage.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't see anything out of the ordinary on the host node. There are also other KVMs running on this host and nothing should anything. Storage is just a qcow2 file